# Why was 50 chosen for the 50-move rule?

Tags: history, 50-move-rule

The reason for the 50-move rule, along with the triple-repetition rule is to make chess definitely finite. How did one arrive at the number 50? What would change if it was 40 or 60? Is the number 50 chosen carefully?

Comment: I've never seen the 50 move rule actually invoked, since maybe 6th grade.

Comment: @TonyEnnis, that's because you haven't seen [this](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1497429) (utterly absurd) game.  (Actually, the 50-move rule isn't invoked in this game, but Nakamura tricks the computer into making errors when it tries to avoid the 50-move rule.)

Comment: @Kyralessa: Wow! Just... WOW

Comment: Don't make the mistake of showing that game to your seven-year-old, like I did.  Apparently he decided that if that tedious back-and-forth stuff was good enough for Nakamura, it was good enough for him as well.

Comment: @kyralessa that game is cool.  You can see Nakamura figuring out how the computer is working, and then using this as a weapon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> At one time, it was believed that all winnable endgames could be won
>   within fifty moves. However, in the early twentieth century, some
>   exceptions were found, including A. A. Troitsky's (1866-1942) analysis
>   of the two knights endgame as well as the endgame of a rook and bishop
>   versus a rook. The rules of chess were revised several times to admit
>   exceptions to the fifty-move rule for certain specific situations.
>   Early on, the fifty-move rule applied to tournament games but not to
>   match games (Troitzky 2006:197).

SOURCE: [Fifty-move rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule)

Comment: This is interesting.  There are some complex endgames that can not in fact be won in fifty moves - for example, multiple pieces vs. queen - but that can be won.

Comment: @Andrew Latham: This [table of "pawnless endgames"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawnless_chess_endgame#Tables), under the "longest win" column, provides additional examples too; note that Stiller and Nunn both say 243 is the longest.

Comment: @Blunders: see my comment to Andrew's answer [here](http://chess.stackexchange.com/a/131/86): there's a setup in which it takes White 517 moves to force a winning endgame - not even mate!

Comment: @Daniel  I guess those extremely long endgames include captures (which are relevant for the 50 move rule), don't they?

Comment: @user1583209 No!  It's 517 moves to get to a capture (which creates a "quickly" winnable end-game. (And the in the particular case, there are no pawns).

Comment: Most unfortunate. The last of the fundamental mate patterns (two knights vs pawn) takes 115 moves.